# In Swashbuckle oauth 2 password flow, username and password are not passed in headers

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, swagger, swashbuckle

I am using swashbuckle.core in my project.
Below is the SwaggerConfig.cs:

```
    using System.Web.Http;
    using Swashbuckle.Application;
    using WebActivator;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System;
    using Swashbuckle.Swagger;
    using System.Web.Http.Description;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Http.Filters;

public class SwaggerConfig
    {

        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration

                 .EnableSwagger(c =>
                 {
                     c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Test.Framework.Rest.ApplicationService");
                       c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
                     c.PrettyPrint();



                    c.OAuth2("oauth2")
                        .Description("OAuth2 Password Grant")
                         .Flow("password")
                         .TokenUrl("https://BLR2TCM29.test/SecureTokenServiceRestV4.0/api/authorization/requestaccesstoken")
                            .Scopes(scopes =>
                                        {
                              scopes.Add("oauth2", "AUTHORIZATION");

                                 }
                                 );


                     c.OperationFilter<AddRequiredAuthorizationHeaderParameter>();


                 })
                 .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                 {
                     c.EnableOAuth2Support(
                     clientId: "Sample_App",
                     clientSecret: "xxxxx",
                     realm: "test-realm",
                     appName: "Swagger UI",
                     additionalQueryStringParams: new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "loginname", "password" } });
                 });


        }


        public class AddRequiredAuthorizationHeaderParameter : IOperationFilter
        {
            public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
            {
                var actFilters = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline();
                var allowsAnonymous = actFilters.Select(f => f.Instance).OfType<OverrideAuthorizationAttribute>().Any();
                if (allowsAnonymous)
                    return; // must be an anonymous method

                if (operation.security == null)
                    operation.security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();


                var oAuthRequirements = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            { "oauth2", new string[]{ "AUTHORIZATION"} }
        };

                operation.security.Add(oAuthRequirements);
            }

        }
        private static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
        {
            return System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\bin\Test.Rest.ApplicationService.Swagger.xml";
        }
    }
```

API is getting hit for token but headers values i.e. username and password are not present.

Please let me know if I am missing any configuration.

Any example for swashbuckle oauth2 password flow will be helpful.

IMPORTANT:don't provide solution for Swashbuckle.Aspnet as I am using Swashbuckle.Core

Comment: I think there is a swagger-ui bug related to this: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4192

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to find the reason why it was not working. 
Swashbuckle pass the data in body instead of header that also form data type.

[image: screenshot the data]

For receiving data on the api side:

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost()]
    [Route(RELATIVE_PATH + AUTHORIZATION + "/requestauthenticationaccesstoken/")]
    public OAuthResponse AuthenticationAccessToken([FromBody] UserData value)
```

UserData contains getter setter for username,password,scope and grant_type.

After this oauth2 password flow authentication works fine.